# MSMQ - Remote Computer is not available when peeking a message

Tags: .net, msmq, messaging

I am trying to connect to a private MSMQ on another server within out network.  The connection is made from a DMZ server into the internal network and are not on the same domain.

As I understand I can still connect to a remote server as long as the addressing is correct to the queue.

When I peek the message I get the following error:
**Remote Computer is not available**

The queue: FormatName:DIRECT=OS:10.0.9.171\private$\test.queue1

We have ports open on 1801, 2013, 2105.

I've also found this info on MSDN:

Opening a remote queue with peek access requires a direct connection to the computer where the queue resides. You cannot peek at the messages in a queue that resides on a computer that has no direct connection to the computer where your application is running. An RPC session must be established with the remote computer during calls to peek at messages. For more information, see Opening Remote Queues with Peek or Receive Access.

Is the above process transparent when calling the API? I mean how would I even open a "direct RPC connection?"

Can someone offer some guidance on how to peek a queue on a remote machine?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need [port 135 to be open.](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/johnbreakwell/archive/2008/04/29/clear-the-way-msmq-coming-through.aspx)

I've also covered successful remote access to MSMQ over RPC [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/johnbreakwell/archive/2010/03/24/understanding-how-msmq-security-blocks-rpc-traffic.aspx).

Comment: I have now opened the port, but I notice that I now get an 'Access to Message Queuing System is denied' error. I have also set 'Disable un-authenticated RPC calls' option to unchecked and no luck. However, when I open up the EventLog I can see logon attempts with a null SID which fails? I'm using direct queue path addressing to the remote server. Surely, I shouldn't be seeing log-on attempts to AD? Any ideas as to what is wrong here?

Comment: I got this working in the end. I needed to allow READ & PEEK permission on ANONYMOUS user for that specific queue. Thanks for your help.